# Rails turbolinks break submit remote form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks, remote-forms

I'm having a rather weird problem using Rails 4, Turbolinks and a remote form. I have a form looking like:

```
<%= form_for [object], remote: true do |f| %>                                                   
    <td><%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %></td>                                     
    <td><%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %></td>                                   
    <td><%= f.submit button_name, class: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary' %></td>
<% end %>
```

This form adds (creates) a new object. It does however not always work:

- When I load the page directly using the URL or a refresh; it works
- When I navigate from my app to this page; it fails

When disabling Turbolinks for this link, the page worked perfectly.

I have two questions:

1. Why doesn't this work? Is this because the remote handlers aren't attached to the button because of a JQuery/Turbolinks problem?
2. How can I work around this problem?

Thanks in advance.

**Solution**

Thanks to @rich-peck, the solution was to add a piece of javascript that manually submits the form upon clicking the button:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  var id = "#<%= dom_id(f.object) %>";
  var inputs = $(id).parent().find('input');
  console.log(inputs);
  $(id).parent().find('button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(id).append(inputs.clone());
    $(id).submit();
  });
<% end %>
```

This code adds javascript to the form table row, getting the inputs, appending them to the ID and submitting the form. The preventDefault(); prevents the query from getting sent twice when the page is refreshed and the form actually works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Turbolinks**

As mentioned, the problem with Turbolinks is that it reloads the `<body>` part of the DOM with an ajax call - meaning JS is not reloaded, as it's in the head

The typical way around this issue is to [`delegate`](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_delegate.asp) your JS from the `document`, like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#your_element", function() {
    //your code here
});
```

Because `document` is always going to be present, it will trigger the JS continuously

---

**Remote**

With your issue, it's slightly more tricky

The problem is you're relying on the [JQuery UJS](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-tour-of-rails-jquery-ujs) (unobtrusive JavaScript) engine of Rails, which is difficult to remedy on its own

We've never had this issue & we use Turbolinks all the time - so I suppose the problem could be with how you're constructing your form / handling the request. [This GitHub](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/298) seemed to recreate the issue, and it was to do with the table

Maybe you could try:

```
<%= form_for [object], remote: true do |f| %>                                                   
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>                                     
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>                              
    <%= f.submit button_name, class: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - the form is indeed in a table (we are using some kind of excel-like view with an add-row at the bottom and rows that are inline-editable, so this will be the cause of the problem too. I'll add a piece of Javascript for each line that submits the form when clicking on the button to work around the problem.

Comment: You could try a manual ajax call - populating the data from the specific elements?

Comment: I'll indeed try that and get back to you!

Comment: Thanks - looking forward to getting it fixed!

Comment: I fixed it indeed with a manual call, I added the piece of code to my question. Thank you!

Comment: I have come across the exact same thing, with Turbolinks 5 and Rails 5, is there another way around this nowadays?

Comment: Turbolinks still works in the same way -- it just uses different hooks now. If you post a question, and link to it on here, I'll answer it for you if you like!

Answer (score 4):

Turbolinks don't fully reload your page, but only part of it. This is what makes them so fast, however if you have JavaScript requiring a full page reload you will run into trouble. The reason it does work with a refresh is because now you force the page to fully reload.

Edit: This gem might be worth trying out: https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks

For a little bit of extra information about the inner workings of turbolinks: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks

Or: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks

P.s. Also make sure the javascript_include_tag is within the head tag (and not in the body)

Comment: No - that's in the head.

Comment: My javascript_include_tag was on the body... thanks @rails4guides.com